# Compare two text files and find the difference

Tags: file, powershell, filecompare

How to get the lines of text in a txt file, if I compare 2 text files.
I have 2 test files.
 mba.txt and mbanew.txt

mba.txt

```
Pre-Validation/SalesandServiceinvoicing,SalesandServiceinvoicing  
Pre-Validation/SalesandServiceinvoicing/Salesinvoice,Salesinvoice   
IDT-BTStarProject,IDT-BTStarProject,IDT
```

mbanew.txt

```
Pre-Validation/SalesandServiceinvoicing,SalesandServiceinvoicing    
Pre-Validation/SalesandServiceinvoicing/Salesinvoice,Salesinvoice     
IDT-BTStarProject,IDT-BTStarProject,IDT  
IDT-BTStarProject/BBP,BBP  
IDT-BTStarProject/ARIS,ARIS  
IDT-BTStarProject/Servicetaxratemaster,Servicetaxratemaster
```

So i want to find out how many lines of text file have been missed out in mbanew.txt and i need get those text lines.
here in the above example, my answer is  2 and the output  should be :

```
IDT-BTStarProject/BBP,BBP    
IDT-BTStarProject/ARIS,ARIS  
IDT-BTStarProject/Servicetaxratemaster,Servicetaxratemaster
```

I tried with this code in PowerShell

```
cls
compare-Object -referenceobject $(get-content "D:\mba.txt") -differenceobject $(get-content "D:\mbanew.txt")
```

but in vain.

Comment: What exactly wrong with `Compare-Object` approach?

Answer (score 1):

`compare-object` is pathetic if you expect it to behave something like a unix `diff`. Best alternatives according to me will be

1. [`fc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_File_Compare) MS-DOS Command
2. [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/?lang=en) GUI Diff Tool

A simple `fc` usage will give output as

```
`fc mba.txt mbanew.txt`

Comparing files mba.txt and mbanew.txt
***** mba.txt
Pre-Validation/SalesandServiceinvoicing,SalesandServiceinvoicing
Pre-Validation/SalesandServiceinvoicing/Salesinvoice,Salesinvoice
IDT-BTStarProject,IDT-BTStarProject,IDT
***** mbanew.txt
Pre-Validation/SalesandServiceinvoicing,SalesandServiceinvoicing
Pre-Validation/SalesandServiceinvoicing/Salesinvoice,Salesinvoice
IDT-BTStarProject,IDT-BTStarProject,IDT
IDT-BTStarProject/BBP,BBP
IDT-BTStarProject/ARIS,ARIS
IDT-BTStarProject/Servicetaxratemaster,Servicetaxratemaster
*****
```